# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'softwareproject.o_r_f_o_l_s' doesn't exist error in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

How to solve this problem?

error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'softwareproject.o_r_f_o_l_s' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `o_r_f_o_l_s` (`region`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (4165dsF, 3, 2018-09-06 20:33:58, 2018-09-06 20:33:58))

my migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

    class CreateORFOLsTable extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('o_r_f_o_ls', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('ORFOLId');
                $table->string('region');

                $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('user_id')->references('userId')->on('all_users');

                $table->timestamps();

            });
        }

        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::dropIfExists('o_r_f_o_ls');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is that really the name of the table, or have you abbreviated it for your question? There's a 64 character limit on table names in MySQL.

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from this migration? The error is on an insert, yet this migration doesn't have any inserts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

careless mistake..

```
according to the model, table name should change as o_r_f_o_l_s.`
```

mistake is table name.
I suppose it's helpful to some users solve that question.

Comment: Why on earth would you name a table like this?

Comment: according to the error o_r_f_o_l_s table doen't exit. so change table name as it is.when we try php artisan make:model ORFOLs -m command create automatically model and migration. when some times edit migration can happen this kind of careless mistake.

Comment: @Devon I guess this crazy table name is the ["snake case" plural name](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) of that crazy all-caps model name.  Personally I would try to stick with Laravel's conventions for model names (ie single capital letter), there are probably other subtle issues that will turn up with such names.